# XML 1.0 incremental value (counter)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'd like to transform XML file to have incremental counter in the output. I'm trying to do so but every approach fails. It needs to be dane in XSLT-1.0.

This is fragment of XML stylesheet which doesn't work, but you'll get the idea:

```
<tripSequence>
    <xsl:variable name="cnt" select="0"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="BODY/DBOUT/TRIP/PLANCOMPONENTS/*[starts-with(name(),'NO')]">
        <xsl:if test="TYPE = 'PICKUP' or TYPE = 'DELIVERY'">
            <numberInSequence><xsl:value-of select="$cnt"/></numberInSequence>
            <xsl:variable name="cnt" select="$cnt + 1"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</tripSequence>
```

How to put incremental value every time when if-condtion is met?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables in XSLT are actually constants. You can only apply different values to variables if you use recursion. To obtain what you want, you can simply print the `position()` of the node replacing the `if` test with a predicate in the loop:

```
<tripSequence>
    <xsl:for-each select="BODY/DBOUT/TRIP/PLANCOMPONENTS/*[starts-with(name(),'NO')][TYPE = 'PICKUP' or TYPE = 'DELIVERY']">
         <numberInSequence><xsl:number value="position()"/></numberInSequence>
    </xsl:for-each>
</tripSequence>
```

This will count only the actual nodes that match the `for-each`. If you use `position()` with the `if` test instead of the predicate, it will also record the positions of the elements that match the predicate and not the `if`, and may not be sequential.

The count starts at 1. If you want to count from zero, you have to subtract 1.